# Só renderizar meu elemento se ele não estiver vazio com o *ngIf

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Tenho a seguinte variável:

```
listAtributos: any[] = [];
```

No meu template quero checar se ela está vazia, se estiver, não mostrar o conteúdo, se tiver algo dentro dela, mostrar o conteúdo da div.

Tentei algo como:

```
<div *ngIf="listAtributos != null"
```

Nessa condição a div é renderizada, mesmo que esteja em seu estado inicial `(listAtributos: any[] = [].`

Em algum momento do meu código essa lista é copulada, quando isso acontece, eu quero que essa div seja mostrada. Porém, ela está sendo mostrada com essa condição != null.

Estou aplicando a condição de forma incorreta? Tem algo que eu ainda não percebi? Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
<div *ngIf="listAtributos.length > 0">
//Código
</div>
```

ou

```
<div *ngIf="listAtributos.length">
//Código
</div>
```